# Find the remainder without differentiation

Tags: polynomials, chinese-remainder-theorem

The degree of $f(x)$ is not given.
When $f(x)$ is divided by $(x-3)$ the remainder is $15$ and when $f(x)$ is divided by $(x-1)^2$ the remainder is $2x+1$.

Now we need to find the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $(x-1)^2(x-3)$.

My attempt : I used remainder theorem and differentiation to obtain the answer $2x^2-2x+3$

Can we find the remainder without using differentiation?

Comment: Have you tried the Chinese Remainder Theorem? (I added that tag.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the remainder when a polynomial is divided by a product of numbers whose remainders are known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524258/finding-the-remainder-when-a-polynomial-is-divided-by-a-product-of-numbers-whose) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(x-1)%5E2(x-3)%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%242x%5E2-2x%2B3%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Apolynomial%2C%20OR%20content%3Aremainder&p=1). Note there are also quite a few other duplicates found, e.g., [Remainders and polynomial division](/q/1039477) ...

Comment: (cont) (with the [answer](/a/1039486) there including a helpful link to Wikipedia's [Polynomial remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem) article), [Remainder of the polynomial](/q/724875), [Finding remainder](/q/1416935), [Remainder for the polynomial division](/q/3671360) (although the [answer](/a/3671423) there using differentiation), [Polynomial remainder problem.](/q/2320784) (with its [answer](/a/2320807) also using differentiation), etc. Note there are also several AoPS threads, e.g., ...

Comment: (cont.) [Algebra.......](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1139417p5341664), [Crazy Polynomials](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2116290p15363463) (where the first of the current $2$ solutions uses differentiation), etc.